# Reputation list contains someone else question/answer?

Tags: support

I have noticed that there is a reference to someone else question in my reputation list. This is quite weird as I never participated in any questions related to Silverlight.

[image: reputations list]

Did you noticed that issue before? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a bug, you made suggested edit to that post and you gain 2 rep for that, now that post is removed and you lose -2 rep. you can see the list of [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916110/tom?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) you made.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense now. Completely forgot about reputation point for edits. Many thanks for your clarifications.