# Mysterious -2 on SO due to post removed which was never posted

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

I have been awarded with [-2     18:11  removed Set TextView text from html-formatted string resource in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml/17719491#17719491).

But i cannot find answer which i have posted and got removed.(because i never posted answer there )

*Note: I don't give answer in that tag's too.* Still i have been awarded with [-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml/17719491#17719491).

Neither i have Up-voted nor Down-voted any answer/question on that page .

Can anybody explain why that `-2` is awarded to me .

See My [SO Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224265/tushar-gupta?tab=reputation)

[image]

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206861/reputation-list-contains-someone-else-question-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had a edit on that post which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17719491/revisions).

If that was a suggested edit you would have gained 2 rep which was removed when the post was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you lost 2 rep, it sounds like you made a suggested edit to that post at some time in the past. The post has now been removed, and the +2 bonus for an accepted edit has been removed with it.